# Cómo calcular una raíz cuadrada con precisión en Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, math

Hola a todos y muchas gracias de antemano

Tengo que desarrollar una función llamada square_root que tome como parámetros dos números reales, y devuelva la raíz cuadrada del primero calculada con la precisión especificada por el segundo

El primer número representa la raíz cuadrada que queremos calcular y el segundo número representa la precisón del resultado. De momento, tengo hecho esto, pero no se cómo continuar:

main.py

```
import functions
num1 = 25.0
num2 = 1E-10      # (0,00000000001) Precisión especificada
root = functions.square_root(num1, num2)
print(root)

functions.py
def square_root(num1, num2):
```

Ejemplo:

Por ejemplo, si (num1) es igual a 25 y (num2) es igual a 1E-10 (0,00000000001), result iría tomando los siguientes valores:

```
25 # De la forma que lo hice si obtengo este valor
13.0 # De la forma que lo hice si obtengo este valor
7.461538461538462
5.406026962727994
5.015247601944898
5.000023178253949
5.000000000053722
5.0 # De la forma que lo hice si obtengo este valor
```

Comment: Vince, aquí no estamos para darte ideas. Si quieres que te ayudemos a corregir el código, deberías mostrarlo.

Comment: Entiendo que no se tratará de algo tan trivial como dejar que python te lo calcule  (por ejemplo con `math.sqrt()`) y luego quitar los decimales que sobren, sino que se trata de que implementes tú mismo una función que encuentre la raiz cuadrada sin hacer uso de esa funcionalidad python. Esto puede hacerse por ejemplo con el [método de Newton](https://www.school-for-champions.com/algebra/square_root_approx.htm#.XZsF0kb7SCo), lo que además encaja con la idea de "parar al alcanzar cierta precisión". ¿Es así como debes hacerlo?

Comment: no pongo más del codigo porque como dije en la entrada anteriormente escrita "DE MOMENTO, TENGO HECHO ESTO, PERO NO SÉ CÓMO CONTINUAR"

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la funcion round(), pero segun entendi,el segundo numero indica la pesicion, por lo que a round(), debes pasarle no la precision tal y como tu la tratas. Mira mi ejemplo:

```
import numpy as np

def square_root(numero, precision):
    cifras_despues_de_la_coma = len(str(int(1/precision))) - 1
    return round(np.sqrt(numero), cifras_despues_de_la_coma)
```

Los resultados serian, por ejemplo:

```
precision = 1E-2
print(square_root(5, precision))
>> 2.24
precision = 1E-8
print(square_root(5, precision))
>> 2.23606798
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente podrías usar la función `round()`, te dejo mi solución.

```
def square_root(numero_raiz, numero_decimales):
    return round(float(numero_raiz ** 0.5), numero_decimales)


In [2]square_root(5, 15)
Out[2]: 2.23606797749979
```

Sí es una práctica o trabajo académico, quedaría más "guay" si lo haces sin librerías, y simplemente haces la raíz cuadrada de un número, elevando dicho número a 1/2 :)